# Count the semiprime numbers in the given range [a..b]

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I am solving Codility problem [CountSemiprimes: Count the semiprime numbers in the given range [a..b]](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/11-sieve_of_eratosthenes/count_semiprimes/).

#### Task description

A *prime* is a positive integer X that has exactly two distinct divisors: 1 and X. The first few prime integers are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 and 13.

A *semiprime* is a natural number that is the product of two (not necessarily distinct) prime numbers. The first few semiprimes are 4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26.

You are given two non-empty arrays P and Q, each consisting of M integers. These arrays represent queries about the number of semiprimes within specified ranges.

Query K requires you to find the number of semiprimes within the range (P[K], Q[K]), where 1 ≤ P[K] ≤ Q[K] ≤ N.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

- N is an integer within the range [1..50,000];
- M is an integer within the range [1..30,000];
- each element of arrays P, Q is an integer within the range [1..N];
  P[i] ≤ Q[i].

#### My solution

My current score is 66% and problem is preformance for large data set:

- large random, length = ~30,000
- all max ranges

Test says, that it should take about 2sec, but my solution takes over 7sec.

This is my current solution

```
class Solution {
    private static List<Integer> getPrimes(int max) {
        List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>(max / 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            if (isPrime(i))
                primes.add(i);

        return primes;
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int val) {
        if (val <= 1)
            return false;
        if (val <= 3)
            return true;

        for (int i = 2, sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(val); i <= sqrt; i++)
            if (val % i == 0)
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean[] getSemiPrimes(int N) {
        List<Integer> primes = getPrimes(N);
        boolean[] semiPrimes = new boolean[N + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++) {
            if (primes.get(i) > N)
                break;

            for (int j = i; j < primes.size(); j++) {
                if (primes.get(j) > N || N / primes.get(i) < primes.get(j))
                    break;

                int semiPrime = primes.get(i) * primes.get(j);

                if (semiPrime <= N)
                    semiPrimes[semiPrime] = true;
            }
        }

        return semiPrimes;
    }

    public static int[] solution(int N, int[] P, int[] Q) {
        boolean[] semiPrimes = getSemiPrimes(N);
        int[] res = new int[P.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
            for (int j = P[i]; j <= Q[i]; j++)
                if (semiPrimes[j])
                    res[i]++;

        return res;
    }
}
```

Any ideas about improving performance? My last one was to remove `Set` for holding semi-primes with array. It helped me to solve couple of performance tests.

Comment: You should use something like the Sieve of Eratosthenes to generate the primes. That should be faster I think.

Comment: @marstran I have checked it. `for` loop up to `sqrt(n)` is the most efficient way to find all primes `[0...n]`

Comment: it's definitely not the most efficient way to find all primes up to n. It works better to check if a single value is prime or not, but there are ways to make it much faster, like use `i += 2` instead of `i++`, or just [check divisibility for values in the form `6*i ± 1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Pseudocode). A sieve is always the best way to generate a prime list. You've done the benchmark incorrectly

Comment: @phuclv In any case, this will not give an increase of 3 times

Comment: The `boolean` array seems smart, but I wonder if we can do even better? Put all you semiprimes in a sorted array and use binary search for `p[i]` and `q[i]`. The difference between the two indices found is the number of semiprimes in the range. You may try.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik A for-loop up to `sqrt(n)` may be the fastest way to determine whether a number is prime. However, it's _not_ the fastest to generate a list of primes. A sieve is a lot faster for that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Java solution which scores 100% is as follow:

- Find the set of prime numbers which their products is not greater than `N`
- create semi-prime from them as a bit wise array of 0 and 1
- create a prefix sum of the semi-primes
- calculate the queries from `P[i]` to `Q[i]` in `O(M)`

The whole algorithm is of `O(N * log(log(N)) + M)` stated by the Codility's test result evaluation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CountSemiPrime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] P = new int[] {1, 4, 16};
        int[] Q = new int[] {26, 10, 20};
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( new CountSemiPrime().solution( 26, P, Q ) ) );
    }

    public int[] solution(int N, int[] P, int[] Q) {

        Integer[] primes = sieve(N/2+1);

        int[] temp = new int[N+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < primes.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < primes.length; j++) {
                int semiPrime = primes[i] * primes[j];
                if(semiPrime <= N)
                    temp[semiPrime] = 1;
            }
        }

        int[] prefix = new int[N+1];
        for (int i = 1; i < temp.length; i++) {
            prefix[i] = temp[i] + prefix[i-1];
        }

        int[] retVal = new int[P.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < retVal.length; i++) {
            retVal[i] = prefix[Q[i]] - prefix[P[i]-1];
        }

        return retVal; 
    }


    public Integer[] sieve(int n) {

        boolean[] temp = new boolean[n+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = true;
        }
        temp[0] = temp[1] = false;

        int i = 2;
        while (i * i <= n) {
            removeProducts( temp, i );
            i++;
        }

        List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
            if(temp[j])
                ret.add( j );
        }

        return ret.toArray( new Integer[ret.size()] );
    }

    private void removeProducts(boolean[] temp, int i) {
        for (int j = i*i; j < temp.length; j++) {
            if(temp[j] && j % i == 0) {
                temp[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can precompute an array A of size N+1, which stores at A[i] the number of semiprimes less than or equal to i. Then a query `p, q` can be computed immediately: the number of semiprimes between p and q (inclusive) is `A[q] - A[p-1]`.

This array can be computed efficiently: let P be an array of primes less than or equal to N/2. Then (in java-like pseudocode):

```
A = new int[N+1]
for (int p : P) {
  for (int q : P) {
      if (p*q > N || q > p) break;
      A[p*q] = 1
  }
}

for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    A[i] += A[i-1]
```

This works by marking the semiprimes with a `1` in the array, and then taking a cumulative sum. It runs in better than O(N^2) and worse than O(N) time -- there's about `N/2logN` primes in `P`, so the first part is O((N/logN)^2), and the summing-up is O(N). [Note: I guess the first part has better complexity than O((N/log N)^2) because of the early termination of the inner loop, but I've not proved that]. Computing the primes in `P` is O(N log log N) using the sieve of Erastothenes.

A Python version of this program takes 0.07s to precompute `A` for `N=50000`, and to perform 30000 queries. It gets a perfect score (100) when run on codility, and codility reports that it detects the code to be have complexity O(N log(log(N)) + M).

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses Sieve of Eratosthenes such that smallest prime factor of number N is stored in the array Factor[N].
Then if Factor[N/Factor[N]] = 0, we have a semi prime number incrementing a sum scan.
The entry r of the returned array will then be:
A[r]=Inclusive_scan[Q[r]]-Inclusive_scan[P[r]-1].

Here the corresponding python code [(100% task score)](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingHSYMM6-UCK/):

```
def solution(N, P, Q):
 A=len(P)*[0]
 if N<4:
     return A
#Minimum prime factor of n stored in Factor[n]
 Factor = [0] * (N + 1)
 i = 2
 while (i * i <= N):
  if (Factor[i] == 0):
   k = i * i
   while (k <= N):
    if (Factor[k] == 0):
     Factor[k] = i;
    k += i
  i += 1
#Count semi prime numbers and store 
#sum scan in array Incluse_scan   
 Incluse_scan=[0] * (N + 1)
 cnt_semi=0
 for k in range(4,N+1):
     if Factor[k]!=0:
         d=int(k/Factor[k])
         if Factor[d]==0:
             cnt_semi+=1                 
     Incluse_scan[k]=cnt_semi   
#Do the difference of semi prime counters
 for r in range(0,len(P)):
     if(P[r]<=4):
       min_inclusive=0
     else:
       min_inclusive=P[r]-1 
     A[r]=Incluse_scan[Q[r]]-Incluse_scan[min_inclusive] 
 return A
```

Comment: Yes it does . You need to select Python instead of Java for the language you are using. Here the proof https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingHSYMM6-UCK/

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 100% solution

```
require 'prime'
require 'set'

def solution(n, p, q)
    primes = Prime::EratosthenesGenerator.new.take_while {|i| i <= n/2 }
    sqrt = Math.sqrt(n)
    semiprimes = primes.each_with_index.inject(Set.new) do |acc, (e,i)|
      break acc if e > sqrt.to_i
      primes[i..-1].each{ |pr| e*pr > n ? break : acc << e*pr }
      acc
    end
    offsets = semiprimes.sort.each_with_index.inject([]) {|acc,(el,i)| acc[el] = i+1;acc  }

    p.each_with_index.inject([]) do |acc, (el,i)|
      next acc << 0 unless offsets[el..q[i]]

      left =  offsets[el..q[i]].detect{|a| a}
      next acc << 0 unless left

      right = offsets[el..q[i]].reverse_each.detect{|a| a}

      acc << ((left..right).size)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my 100% solution in C++. you can find other answers in my [github](https://github.com/Behrouz-m/Codility) in cpp:

```cpp
vector<int> getFactArr(int n) {
    vector<int> f(n+1, 0);
    f[1] = 1;
    int i = 2;
    while (i * i <= n) {
        if (f[i] == 0) {
            int k = i * i;
            while (k <= n) {
                if (f[k] == 0)
                    f[k] = i;
                k+=i;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    return f;
}

vector<int> solution(int N, vector<int> &P, vector<int> &Q) {
    vector<int> F = getFactArr(N);
    vector<int> prefix_semi_primes(N + 1, 0);

    for (int x = 1; x <= N; x++) {
        if (F[x] > 0 && F[x / F[x]] == 0)
            prefix_semi_primes[x]++;
        prefix_semi_primes[x] += prefix_semi_primes[x - 1];
    }

    const int M = P.size();
    vector<int> ans(M, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        ans[i] = prefix_semi_primes[Q[i]] - prefix_semi_primes[P[i] - 1];
    }

    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting problem. I tried it and got 88% score.

Here is my strategy:

- I used [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for getting a `BitSet` for primes.
- Now I looped over that `BitSet` and added all the primes in a `primeList`.
- My strategy for finding semi-primes was a bit interesting and I reached to this strategy incrementally.

```
private static boolean isSemiPrime(int n) {
    if(n==1 || n==0 || primeBitSet.get(n))
        return false;
    int firstFactor = findFirstFactor(n);
    if(firstFactor==0 || firstFactor==1)
        return false;
    return isPrime(n / firstFactor);
}

private static int findFirstFactor(int n) {

    for (int i = 0; i < primeList.size(); i++) {
        if (n % primeList.get(i) == 0)
            return primeList.get(i);
    }
    // should never be the case
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not very sure why I got 88% score. (What I'm missing)

But the most interesting and worth noting part was the strategy to check whether a given number is Semi-prime or not:

- Find the first prime factor of the given number
- Then checking that the quotient of the given number and the first-prime-factor is a prime or not.
- If it is prime, then the given number is a semi-prime, otherwise the given number is not a semi prime.

Note that I also did a very naive form of book-keeping where I made a cumulative array which stores the total number of semi-primes till index `x`. One time filling this array and answering each of the query in `O(1)` is again obvious optimization.

Not related to the solution, but my `Task Score` was 88%, `Correctness` 100% and `Performance` 80%. I'll be happy to hear suggestions and anything that I missed.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isSemiPrime = (num) => {
    let cnt = 0
    for (let i = 2; cnt < 2 && i * i <= num; ++i) {
        while (num % i == 0) {
            num /= i
            ++cnt
        }
    }
    if (num > 1)++cnt
    return cnt == 2 ? true : false
}

console.log(
    [4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 38, 39, 46, 49, 51, 55].filter(isSemiPrime)
        .length
)
```

Comment: can you elaborate a little more than just posting the code snippet please?

Answer (score 0):

Here the Javascript version of the solution, but it is 55%:

```
function solution(N, P, Q) {

  function isPrime(num) {
    for(var i = 2; i < num; i++)
      if(num % i === 0) return false;
    return num > 1;
  }

  const min = Math.min(...P)
  const max = Math.max(...Q)
  const A = []
  for(let i=min;i<max;i++) {
      for(let j=min;j<max;j++) {
          if (isPrime(i) && isPrime(j)) {
              const prod = j * i
              if (prod > max) break
              if (A.includes(prod)) continue
              A.push(j * i)
          }
      }
  }

  const result = []
  for(let i=0;i<P.length;i++) {
      for(let j=P[i];j<=Q[i];j++) {
          result[i] = result[i] || 0
          if (A.includes(j)) {
              result[i]++
          }
      }
  }
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention that the method you use for finding primes is inefficient.

Your code:

```
private static List<Integer> getPrimes(int max) {
    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>(max / 2);

**    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
**        if (isPrime(i))
**            primes.add(i);

    return primes;
}

private static boolean isPrime(int val) {
    if (val <= 1)
        return false;
    if (val <= 3)
        return true;

**    for (int i = 2, sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(val); i <= sqrt; i++)
**        if (val % i == 0)
**            return false;

    return true;
}
```

I have marked the lines to pay attention to.
I would do something like this:

```
private static List<Integer> getPrimes(int max) {
    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>(max / 2);
    primes.add(2);

    for (int i = 3; i < max; i++)
        if (isPrime(i, primes))
            primes.add(i);

    return primes;
}

private static boolean isPrime(int val, List<Integer> primes) {
    int sqrtv = Math.sqrt(val);
    for (int i = 0; i < primes.length(); i++)
    {
        int prime = primes.get(i);
        if (val % primes.get(i) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        } else if (prime > sqrtv) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This plays on the fact that:

1. the only call to isPrime is from getPrimes.  getPrimes will always call val in ascending order.
2. by the time isPrime is called with the parameter val, getPrimes has already got a list of all primes that are smaller than val.
3. there's no point in dividing with non-primes when determining primes.  If we already know that a number 'a' is not divisible by 2, then why bother with dividing it by 4, 6, 8 or 10?  If we know it isn't divisible by 3, then it won't be divisible by 9... so all of the non-prime checks are filtered by using the previously calculated primes only to perform the checking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 100% in c++. I'm using prefixSum. Time complexity O(N * log(log(N)) + M).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

vector<int> solution(int N, vector<int> &P, vector<int> &Q)
{
    vector<bool> sieve(N, true);
    vector<int> ret;
    sieve[0] = sieve[1] = false;
    int i = 2;

    while (i * i <= N)
    {
        if (sieve[i])
        {
            int k = i * i;
            while (k <= N)
            {
                sieve[k] = false;
                k += i;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    vector<int> prefixSum(N + 1, 0);
    
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(N); i++)
        if (sieve[i])
            for (int j = i; j <= N; j++)
            {
                if (j * i > N)
                    break;

                if (sieve[j])
                    prefixSum[j * i]++;
            }

    int carry;
    for (unsigned int i = 5; i < prefixSum.size(); i++)
    {
        carry = prefixSum[i - 1];
        prefixSum[i] += carry;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < P.size(); i++)
        ret.push_back(prefixSum[Q[i]] - prefixSum[P[i] - 1]);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Please detail your answer, only code as answer is not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

A 100% solution broken down. https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingGVNHKU-MA5/

Firstly use the sieve of Eratosthenes to workout what is prime.

```
def get_sieve(n):
    # Use the sieve or Eratosthenes to produce an array of primes 
    # where factor[n] == 0 indicates a prime number
    factors = [0] * (n+1)
    i=2
    i2 = i*i
    while (i2 <= n):
        if not factors[i]:
            k = i2
            while k <= n:
                if not factors[k]:
                    factors[k] = i
                k += i
        i += 1
        i2 = i*i
    return factors
```

Next, determine if the number is semi prime.  If both its factors are prime its semiprime.

```
def is_semi_prime(n, factors):
    if factors[n]: # Check its not a prime
        for r in range(int(n**.5)+1, 1, -1):
            if not n%r:
                d = n//r
                return (not factors[d]) and (not factors[r])
    return False
```

Then scan the range up to N numbers to count slope of increasing semi primes.  simply measure the slope within a slice to see how many semi primes occur during that slice.

```
def solution(N, P, Q):
    # produce a slope of increasing semi primes
    factors = get_sieve(N)
    slope = [0] * (N+1)
    for i in range(1, N+1):
        slope[i] = slope[i-1] + is_semi_prime(i, factors) # Auto casting!! :-)
    # Optimus Prime!
    # print(list(enumerate(slope)))
    return [slope[Q[j]] - slope[P[j]-1] for j in range(len(P))]
```

https://github.com/niall-oc/things/blob/master/codility/count_semiprimes.py
and more at
https://github.com/niall-oc/things/blob/master/codility/

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach. The other efficient solutions in this thread builds a regular Sieve of Eratosthenes (F) with a twist of recording the smallest prime factor in the slot, so semiprimes are those x for which F[x] > 0 and F[x // F[x]] == 0, i.e. dividing by the smallest prime factor yields another prime number.

My approach is a little slower but does not use division, and builds an interesting intermediate: a sieve that computes exactly how many factors make up the prime factorization of the number (and zeros at the primes). For each prime p, I would increment the sieve at position 2p, 3p, 4p,... but also count a factor for p^2, 2p^2, 3p^2..., p^3, 2p^3, 3p^3, 4p^3,... and so forth. The slot for 16 stores the value 4 (prime factorization: 2*2*2*2), because the slot gets hit by visits from 2, 2^2, 2^3 and 2^4.

Then the semiprimes are those positions having exactly 2 prime factors.

After that I build a prefix count of semiprimes with which to answer the queries in constant time.

```
def solution(N, P, Q):
    num_factors = [0] * (N+1)
    for i in range(2, N+1):
        if num_factors[i] == 0:
            # Count visits to multiples of i by adding i each time
            add_visit = i+i
            while add_visit < N+1:
                num_factors[add_visit] += 1
                add_visit += i
            # But squares of prime count as 2 factors, cubes count as 3 etc,
            # so also run visits for multiples of the squares, cubes, etc. 
            power_prime = i*i
            while power_prime < N+1:
                visit = power_prime
                while visit < N+1:
                    num_factors[visit] += 1
                    visit += power_prime
                power_prime *= i
    semiprime_prefix_count = [0] * (N+1)
    for i in range(1, N+1):
        semiprime_prefix_count[i] = semiprime_prefix_count[i-1]
        if num_factors[i] == 2:
            semiprime_prefix_count[i] += 1
    results = []
    for p, q in zip(P, Q):
        results.append(semiprime_prefix_count[q] - semiprime_prefix_count[p-1])
    #print(list(zip(range(N+1),num_factors)))
    #print(list(zip(range(N+1),semiprime_prefix_count)))
    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the usual sieve to get the prime numbers up to N.

Use the prime number to get semi-prime numbers up to N. You can do this by checking any number for two prime factors.

Create prefix sums to store the number of semi-primes up to a particular index.

Finally, get the semi prime counts by subtracting the numbers at the query end and start.

```
vector<int> solution(int N, vector<int> &P, vector<int> &Q)                     
{                                                                               
  vector<int> sieve(N, 0);                                                      
  for (int prime = 2; prime * prime <= N; ++prime) {                            
    for (int composite = prime * prime; composite <= N; composite += prime) {   
      if (!sieve[composite - 1]) sieve[composite - 1] = prime;                  
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             
                                                                                
  vector<int> semi_primes;                                                      
  for (int i = 3; i < N; ++i) {                                                 
    const int e = sieve[i];                                                     
    if (e > 0 && !sieve[i / e]) semi_primes.push_back(i + 1);                   
  }                                                                             
  if (semi_primes.empty()) semi_primes.push_back(0);                            
                                                                                
  vector<int> prefix_sums(N + 1, 0);                                            
  for (int i = 1, spi = 0; i <= N; ++i) {                                       
    prefix_sums[i] = ((semi_primes[spi] != i) ? spi : ++spi);                   
  }                                                                             
                                                                                
  int M = P.size();                                                             
  vector<int> semi_prime_counts(M, 0);                                          
  for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {                                                 
    semi_prime_counts[i] = prefix_sums[Q[i]] - prefix_sums[P[i] - 1];           
  }                                                                             
                                                                                
  return semi_prime_counts;                                                     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(N, P, Q) {
      // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
    let pr =[];let fn =[]
    for(var i=2;i<=N;i++){
        if(isPrime(i)){
            pr.push(i)
        }
    }
    let spr = [],mul,br=0
    for(var i=0;i<pr.length;i++){
        for(var j=0; j <pr.length;j++){
            mul = pr[i] * pr[j];
            if(mul <= N) {
                spr.push(mul)
            }else{
                br =1;
                break;
            }
        }
        // if(br==1) break;
    }
    let nm = [];
    //let o =0
    for(var i=0;i<=N;i++){
       if(spr.indexOf(i) >=0){
        //    ++o
           nm.push(1)
       }else{
            nm.push(0)
       }

    }

    // spr = Array.from(new Set(spr))
    // spr.sort((a,b)=> a- b)
    let a,b,c
    for(var i =0;i<P.length;i++){
        // a= findme(P[i],spr)
        // b= findme(Q[i],spr)
        // a= nm[P[i]]
        // b= nm[Q[i]]
        c= nm.slice(P[i],Q[i]+1).reduce((a,b)=> a+b)
        // c=c <=0 ? 0 : c+1
        // fn.push(b - a + 1)
        fn.push(c)
    }
    return fn
}

function findme(a,arr){
    for(var i= 0; i< arr.length;i++){
        if(a <= arr[i]) return i;
    }
}

function isPrime(num){
    if (num ===2) return true
    for(var i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
    return num > 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
     * https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingPBRVXK-28Q/
     * time complexity: O(N * log(log N) + M
     * space complexity: O(2N + N)
     */
public class CountSemiPrime {

    /**
     * 2D array for sieving numbers 1..N
     * 1 - prime, 2 - semiprime, 3 - composite
     */
    public int[][] sieve(int N) {
        int[][] sieve = new int[N+1][1];
        for (int i=1; i<=N; i++) {
            sieve[i][0] = 1; // make prime default
        }
        for (int i=2; i<= N; i++) {
            if (sieve[i][0] == 1) { // if this num is prime, tag its multiples as semi-prime
                int next_number = i + i;
                while (next_number <= N) {
                    sieve[next_number][0] = 2;
                    next_number += i;
                }
            }
            // if this num is semi-prime, tag its multiples as composite
            else if (sieve[i][0] == 2) {
                int next_number = i + i;
                while (next_number <= N) {
                    sieve[next_number][0] = 3;
                    next_number += i;
                }
            }
        }
        return sieve;
    }

    public int[] solution(int N, int[] P, int[] Q) {
        // first, we need to establish prime and semi-prime numbers from 1 to N, in a sieve
        int[][] sieve = sieve(N);
        int[] prefix_sum_of_sieve = new int[sieve.length];

        for (int i=1; i<sieve.length; i++) {
            if (sieve[i][0]==2) {
                prefix_sum_of_sieve[i] = prefix_sum_of_sieve[i-1] + 1;
            }
            else {
                prefix_sum_of_sieve[i] = prefix_sum_of_sieve[i-1];
            }
        }

        int[] results = new int[P.length];
        // we count the semiprime of N from P and Q, for each P & Q from the prefix sum
        for (int i=0; i < P.length; i++) {
            results[i] = prefix_sum_of_sieve[Q[i]] - prefix_sum_of_sieve[P[i]-1];
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Hope the explanation / comments are easy to understand.